# Combine two dataframes of different frequncies and unequal lenght in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge, time-series

I need to join/merge two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, that have different frequencies and lengths. In these dataframes the date correspond to the dates of the change in the values (value1 and value2).

The dataframes are:

```
State <- c(A,A,A,B,B,B)
Date1 <- c(01/01/2015, 02/04/2015, 12/01/2016, 03/02/2015, 02/05/2015, 25/01/2016)
Date2 <- C(01/02/2013, 01/04/2015, 19/07/2013, 23/01/2016)
value1 <- c(2.5, 3.2, 2.7, 3.1, 3.6, 2.8)
value2 <- c(0.12, 0.25, 0.2, 0.3)

df1 <- data.frame(State, Date1, value1)
df2 <- data.frame(State, Date2, value2)
```

Then we have:

```
State   Date1       Value1
A       01/01/2015  2.5 
A       02/04/2015  3.2
A       12/01/2016  2.7
B       03/02/2015  3.1
B       02/05/2015  3.6
B       25/01/2016  2.8
```

```
State   Date2       Value2
A       01/02/2013  0.12    
A       01/04/2015  0.25
B       19/07/2013  0.20
B       23/01/2016  0.30
```

I want to join/merge these two dataframes and adjust them to the same time-frequency (daily or weekly). The ideal outcome would be, for daily frequency:

```
State   Date        Value1  Value2
A       01/02/2013  NA      0,12
A       02/02/2013  NA      0,12
(...)
A       01/01/2015  2,5     0,12
(...)
A       01/04/2015  2,5     0,25
A       02/04/2015  3,2     0,25
(...)
A       12/01/2016  2,7     0,25
(...)
B       19/07/2013  NA      0,20
(...)
B       03/02/2015  3,1     0,20
(...)
B       02/05/2015  3,6     0,20
(...)
B       23/01/2016  3,6     0,30
B       24/01/2016  3,6     0,30
B       25/01/2016  2,8     0,30
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by frequency?

Comment: The frequency of the time-series: the observations are repeated daily, weekly, etc. The df's I have now don't have a constant frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I slightly modified the sample you provide i show how to achieve what i think you are looking for using `dplyr`'s `full_join`

```r
library(dplyr)

State1 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
State2 <- c("A","A","B","B")
Date1 <- c("01/01/2015", "01/04/2015", "12/01/2016", "03/02/2015", "02/05/2015", "25/01/2016")
Date2 <- c("01/02/2013", "01/04/2015", "19/07/2013", "23/01/2016")
value1 <- c(2.5, 3.2, 2.7, 3.1, 3.6, 2.8)
value2 <- c(0.12, 0.25, 0.2, 0.3)

df1 <- data.frame(state = State1, date = Date1, value = value1)
df2 <- data.frame(state = State2, date = Date2, value = value2)

full_join(df1, df2, by=c("state", "date"), suffix = c("1","2"))
```

Which would return the following

```
  state       date value1 value2
1     A 01/01/2015    2.5     NA
2     A 01/04/2015    3.2   0.25
3     A 12/01/2016    2.7     NA
4     B 03/02/2015    3.1     NA
5     B 02/05/2015    3.6     NA
6     B 25/01/2016    2.8     NA
7     A 01/02/2013     NA   0.12
8     B 19/07/2013     NA   0.20
9     B 23/01/2016     NA   0.30
```

I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks @Kasp it helped! Now I just need to figure out a way to add the "missing days" between each date and fill the values.